# How to extend a VBO in OpenGL and keep its data?

Tags: opengl, python, vertex-buffer

I'm making a game with infinite, blocky procedurally generated worlds in python, with PyOpenGL. I figured out that allocating all the VBO space at once causes a lot of lag. To fix this, I am dynamically allocating VBOs, and 'growing' them when new data is added. To do this, I map the buffer, save its contents to an array, then unmap it, delete it, create a new VBO with the desired size, and add the old data to it. Is this a good approach?

Also, the game crashes soon after launching, and gives me a segfault. I don't know why this happens. Is there anything I can do?

Here's my code for the VBO class:

````
# imports
import ctypes
import random

import numpy as np
from OpenGL.GL import *

from settings import INIT_VBO_SIZE


class Buffer:
    """
    Buffer

    This is a wrapper for OpenGL buffer objects.
    It supports persistent mapping.
    """

    def __init__(self, id):
        """
        Initializes the buffer.
        """
        self.id = id
        self.buf = glGenBuffers(1)
        self.size = INIT_VBO_SIZE
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.buf)

        # Allocate storage for the buffer using glBufferStorage and specify the desired storage flags
        glBufferStorage(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.size, None,
                        GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT)

    def map_buffer(self):
        """
        Maps the buffer to memory.
        """
        # Bind the buffer
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.buf)

        # Map the buffer to memory using glMapBufferRange
        ptr = glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, self.size,
                               GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT)

        # Create a pointer to the data buffer object
        self.data_ptr = ctypes.cast(ptr, ctypes.POINTER(GLfloat * self.size))

    def unmap_buffer(self):
        """
        Unmaps the buffer.
        """
        # Unmap the buffer
        glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER)

        # Unbind the buffer
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
    
    def extend_vbo(self, new_size):
        self.map_buffer()
        data = np.asarray(self.data_ptr.contents)
        glFlush()
        self.unmap_buffer()
        self.size = new_size
        glDeleteBuffers(1, [self.buf])
        self.buf = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.buf)
        # Allocate storage for the buffer using glBufferData and specify the desired storage flags
        glBufferStorage(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.size, None,
                        GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT)
        self.map_buffer()
        new_data = np.empty(new_size, dtype=data.dtype)
        new_data[:len(data)] = data
        self.data_ptr.contents = new_data.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p))
        glFlush()
        self.unmap_buffer()
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
        glFlush()
        
    def print_buffer_size(self):
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.buf)
        print("Buffer size: %d bytes" % glGetBufferParameteriv(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_BUFFER_SIZE))

    def modify(self, data, offset=0):
        """
        Adds data to the buffer.

        :param data: The data to add to the buffer.
        :param offset: The offset to start writing at.
        """
        # Modify the buffer
        if offset+len(data) > self.size:
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
            self.extend_vbo(offset+len(data))
            glFlush()
        # Print the size of the buffer for debugging
        # self.print_buffer_size()
        self.map_buffer()
        self.data_ptr.contents[offset:offset + len(data)] = data
        glFlush()
        self.unmap_buffer()
    
    def bind(self):
        """
        Binds the buffer.
        """
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.buf)
        
    def __del__(self):
        """
        Deletes the buffer.
        """
        glDeleteBuffers(1, [self.buf])
```
````

Comment: If I understand this right, you store multiple cubes in your VBO and when the camera moves, you create a new, bigger VBO, copy all the data from the previous VBO, and also add more cubes (and delete the old VBO). So over time, your VBO will store hundreds or thousands of cubes, and these cubes are identical except for their position. Am I getting this right?

Comment: No, not exactly. I've implemented a 'chunk' system, When the player moves, new chunks are created, each with its own buffers and initial size, and old ones are destroyed. In a buffer, when the VBO's initial size is passed, the VBO is re-created with the new size, and the old data is copied to it. That's what I'm trying to do. Please do tell me if this is the correct approach.

Comment: There are some problems, for example persistently mapping and then mapping and unmapping every time, or not specifying the `GL_MAP_READ` bit, but if you store all cubes you want to draw in VBOs, that's definitely the biggest problem. You should store the cube mesh only once (like 1 VBO containing 1 cube) and store the positions for example in an array, then looping through the array and for each position drawing a cube. Of course, you can use more efficient data structures instead of the array and you can use instanced rendering, but this is the concept.